# Grails GORM Rest Plugin and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rest, grails, mapping, grails-orm

How can I explicitly set the domain class to be mapped with the GORM REST plugin, so I can still use the hibernate plugin for other domain classes.

Because I get an error when I don't remove the hibernate plugin.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one gorm mapper installed you can tell grails which to use with mappedWith

Add the following to the domain object.

```
static mappedWith = "restclient"
```

For the Rest gorm plugin you will still need the set the URL of the resource.

```
static mapping = {
    url "http://localhost:8080/amazon/books"
}
```

See the [guide](http://projects.spring.io/grails-data-mapping/rest-client/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html).

Comment: the problem is that when i keep hibernate and use that mapping i get the following error :  ORM Mapping Invalid: Specified config option [url] does not exist for class [api.test.Book]

Comment: I used mapWith instead of mappedWith and the error was resolved , I don't know if this is a good solution

Comment: The error you had just was saying that the domain object wasn't set up to be retrieved via rest the rest gorm plugin in so you can store domain objects via rest instead of a db using map with probably left the object as hibernate backed instead.